# replace hyperlink default action to load ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I've been playing around with bootstrap on my local machine trying to make a site, so far so good. Although I'm running into a strange issue and I'm not sure if it is related to bootstrap or something else.

On my site I have a navbar and multiple btn links

here is an example of a menu link

```
<a href="?Page=home">Home</a>
```

her is an exampe of a btn-link

```
<a class="btn btn-info" href="?Page=development">Read More</a>
```

besides the header and what not my body has one empty div

```
<div class="my-body"></div>
```

the goal of this is to have one page that loads the content based on the get variable, which passes it to a get function to load the page it looks like this

```
<?php 
$page_to_load = 'home';
if(isset($_GET['Page'])){
    if(strlen($_GET['Page'])>0){
        $page_to_load = $_GET['Page'];
    }
}
?>
```

then my javascript looks like this

```
$.get('/pages/<?php echo $page_to_load; ?>.php', function(response){
    $('.my-body').html(response);   
});
```

so far all the above code is working as intended but then I thought to myself wouldn't it be nice if when you click a link the entire page didn't reload and it just got the new content... this is where the headache has been for me, I'm basically using the following javascript the thing that is bugging me is that sometimes it seems to work for the navbar links and not the button links. I'm sure I'm missing something or maybe the way I have it just won't work.

```
var _baseLink = 'http://localhost/'
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').click(function(){
        try{
            var _href = $(this).attr('href');
            if(_href.indexOf('#')==-1){
                var _url = document.URL;
                _url = _url.split('?')[0];
                if(_url.indexOf('default.php')<0){
                    _url = _baseLink + 'default.php';
                }
                var _title = document.title;
                var Url = _url + _href;

                //it only sometimes logs this message
                console.log('\r\ntitle:' + _title + '\r\nhref:' + _href + '\r\n_url:' + _url + '\r\nUrl:' + Url);

                //change url
                window.history.pushState({"urlPath": Url}, _title, Url);
                //change page content
                //this could be a bad ajax request but never get it this far.
                $.get(_baseLink + 'pages/' + _href.replace("?Page=", "") + '.php', function(data){ $('.my-body').html(data); }); 
                //prevent page reload
                return false;
            }
        }catch ($ex){
            window.console  && console.log($ex);
        }finally{
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

any help or direction would be greatly appreciated

Comment: When you press a link it does its default action - follows the link. may be you should prevent default action on the links? Try event.preventDefault();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var _baseLink = 'http://localhost/'
/* try to put the script at the bottom of the page
   to avoid using document ready */
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').click(function(e) {

        e.preventDefault(); // use this

        try{
            var _href = $(this).attr('href');
            if(_href.indexOf('#')==-1){
                var _url = document.URL;
                _url = _url.split('?')[0];
                if(_url.indexOf('default.php')<0){
                    _url = _baseLink + 'default.php';
                }
                var _title = document.title;
                var Url = _url + _href;

                //it only sometimes logs this message
                console.log('\r\ntitle:' + _title + '\r\nhref:' + _href + '\r\n_url:' + _url + '\r\nUrl:' + Url);

                //change url
                window.history.pushState({"urlPath": Url}, _title, Url);
                //change page content
                //this could be a bad ajax request but never get it this far.
                $.get(_baseLink + 'pages/' + _href.replace("?Page=", "") + '.php', function(data){ $('.my-body').html(data); }); 
                //prevent page reload
                return false;
            }
        }catch ($ex){
            window.console  && console.log($ex);
        }finally{
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I will be able to test this shortly (when I get home), would a setTimeout be an ok alternative to to having the scripts at the bottom of the page?

Comment: I don't think so, but using $(document).ready is not bad at all. It just impacts performance a little. Using setTimeout is a very bad practice, please avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

First off thank you jstice4all using `e.preventDefault()` made my original code work, and because of making it work I was able to see the problem. my issue was that the content being loaded via ajax exclusively had Anchors with the `.btn` bootstrap class and the class was not the problem rather that i was binding a new click event before they were actually loaded on the page. so i refactored my code to bind the click event after the initial ajax call, and then to rebind the click events for Anchors in my content div after each subsequent request. Thank you for the tips and hope this helps.

Comment: Welcome. You can [delegate events](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) instead of binding/unbinding.

Comment: would that still work for elements that are loaded after an the document, for example the result of an ajax call?